# I have extraneous input ':' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

```
// Define the trend based on the position of the moving average
if ema > ema[1]:
    trend = 'Up'
elif ema < ema[1]:
    trend = 'Down'
else:
    trend = 'Sideways'
```

I try to use the colon (:) and indentation to indicate the start of a block of code but it does not work

```
if ema > ema[1]:
    trend = 'Up'
elif ema < ema[1]:
    trend = 'Down'
else:
    trend = 'Sideways'
```

Compilation error. Line 10: mismatched input 'then' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Comment: That’s not Pine script. Looks like Python. You might have the wrong tag

Comment: Yea, the syntax is off here. [Here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html) is the user manual for you.

Comment: Python uses `#` for comments, not `//`.